# Previous Fragment Momentarily Visible Before Transitioning

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using fragments with an activity:

**CameraActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.CameraFullScreenTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting Camera Fragment");
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, CameraFragment.newInstance(), CameraFragment.TAG)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
        mCurrentPageCount = 0;
    }
}
```

**CameraFragment:**

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    int rotation = getPhotoRotation();
    // Note: Do not send large bitmap images in Bundles and it will lead to Failed Binder Transaction
    // Use CachePot to pass large data
    CachePot.getInstance().push(data);

    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(
                    R.id.fragment_container,
                    EditSavePhotoFragment.newInstance(rotation, mImageParameters.createCopy()),
                    EditSavePhotoFragment.TAG)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();

    setSafeToTakePhoto(true);
}
```

**EditSavePhotoFragment:**

```
  Uri photoUri = ImageUtility.savePicture(getActivity(), bitmap);

  ((CameraActivity) getActivity()).returnPhotoUri(photoUri);
```

`return PhotoUri` invokes another activity using `startActivityForResult`. Before the new activity is started, the `CameraFragment` is momentarily visible before the transition.

```
 public void returnPhotoUri(Uri uri) {
    ...
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

    // we will start a fresh capture.
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, getSupportFragmentManager().POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

    return;
  }
```

Finally, in the onActivityResult method I finish the CameraActivity.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out that the problem was in returnPhotoUri:

```
public void returnPhotoUri(Uri uri) {
    ...
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

    // we will start a fresh capture.
    -- Fix is to use EditSavePhotoFragment.TAG instead of null
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(EditSavePhotoFragment.TAG, getSupportFragmentManager().POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

    return;
  }
```